# Enumeration of temporal partitions

Tags: r, algorithm, sequence, enumeration, partition

I have a series of observations auch as given below where a hypothetical variable `m=3`.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is find all possible partitions (intervals). For example, in the case presented in the picture, if I have one temporal block it starts at `t0` and ends at `t3`.

If I have two temporal blocks, it can be partitioned in two ways: `[t0,t1][t1,t3]` or `[t0,t2][t2,t3]`.

If I have three temporal blocks, I only have one option: `[t0,t1][t1,t2][t2,t3]`

I want to enumerate all these possibilities and calculate the following:

[image]

I can do the coefficients but I cannot enumerate all partitions.

How can I formulate this in R in a way that still works when `m=100`?

Comment: Pleas define "temporal partition". Why, for example, is the second and third expression for `m=2` the same? Also, it isn't clear what it would mean to enumerate them. Are you looking for e.g. a function which returns a list of vectors? The question seems underspecified.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized I had an extra term which I changed. I'll edit more and clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

Say `m = 5` and `i = 3`. You need to choose `2` break points from the vector `1:4`. R has a built-in way of doing so:

```
> combn(4,2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4
```

The third column, for example, corresponds to

```
[t0,t1][t1,t4][t4,t5].
```

More generally, `combn(m-1,i-1)` will generate the cutpoints for the partitions.